# SSH error when installing Google Dataproc with Jupyter

Tags: ssh, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

I have installed a Google DataProc Cluster with Jupyter (https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/tutorials/jupyter-notebook). By using the following command:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create reco-test --zone=europe-west1-d  --master-machine-type n1-standard-2 --master-boot-disk-size 100 --num-workers 2 --worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 --worker-boot-disk-size 50 --project *project* --bucket *bucket* --initialization-actions  gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh`
```

Witch worked as a charm. Afterwards I am trying to do the SSH forwarding, but errors appear:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone=europe-west1-d --ssh-flag="-D 10000" --ssh-flag="-N" --ssh-flag="-n" "reco-test-m" &
```

The error that was given can be find in the picture below as Error 1.

If I remove the "-D"

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone=europe-west1-d --ssh-flag="10000" --ssh-flag="-N" --ssh-flag="-n" "reco-test-m" &
```

The error that was given can be find in the picture below as Error 2.

If I delete "--ssh-flag= "-n""

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone=europe-west1-d --ssh-flag="10000" --ssh-flag="-N" --ssh-flag="-n" "reco-test-m" &`
```

The error that was given can be find in the picture below as Error 3.

Is there somebody who can help me resolving this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2P7R.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're hitting this known issue about the way the arguments are parsed in windows: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/issues/22

Try splitting the `-D 10000` into two separate flags:

```
--ssh-flag="-D" --ssh-flag="10000"
```

Additionally, the `-n` flag is only necessary for running it in the background, and doesn't appear supported in Windows. In general it may be more convenient to keep it running in the foreground anyways, so you can easily `ctrl+C` the the process to kill the tunnel when you're done using it without dealing with background processes (though running it in the background will still terminate automatically when the cluster is deleted).

Update: Since splitting the flag also works in posix systems, I've updated  the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/tutorials/jupyter-notebook#create_an_ssh_tunnel) to now use the separate `--ssh-flag` arguments and also better explain leaving off the `-n` flag when running in the foreground.

Comment: ssh tunnel is created and port 8123 from the cluster is forwarded to my local Windows machine. Chrome opens but still jupyter notebook is not showing. While the url says: **cluster**-m:8123, the window says: 'There is no internet connection'.

Comment: On top: maybe it is good a good idea to indicate in you post that on windows you cannot use "\" as new line indicator and that C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe should be between double quotes: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe".

Comment: What was the full command you used to launch Chrome pointing at the soccks proxy?

Comment: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://reco-test-m:8123" --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:10000" --host-resolver-rules="MAP * 0.0.0.0 , EXCLUDE localhost" --user-data-dir=/tmp/'     Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you make sure the SSH tunnel was still running when trying to access it from Chrome? What if you try a different forwarding port than 10000? What if you remove the "--host-resolve-rules" settings?

Comment: Problem solved! I had two different ports in my gcloud create ssh and google chrome command. Thanks for your help.